# Thin plastic floor covering

Tags: floor, protection

I have laminate flooring coming right up to the base of an external door. This door gets a lot of footfall, and has started to wear the top surface of the laminate where it meets the base of the door.

Does anyone know of a very thin, but durable, adhesive plastic sheeting that I could use to protect the top surface of the laminate for about 10 cm back from the door? It needs to be thin, as not to catch on the door. Iv'e used duck tape to halt the ware, but it looks rubbish; and need a more permanent solution.

If i replace the laminate it'll just happen again.

Something like [this](http://www.leaderfloors.co.uk/accessories-c6/fitting-your-floor-c28/classic-colour-match-self-adhesive-laminate-tape-pp4464/s10863), would be good, but in white/grey, because I don't think I could get it to match exactly. I'm not too sure how durable this would be also.

Comment: They sell very thin door mats with a rubber backing.  I have one that is about 1/8 inch thick and worked great for a door we had that didn't have any clearance.

Comment: Use a Urethane?

Comment: Urethane looks good, but doesn't one need breathing kit to apply it?

Comment: 1/8 inch (3mm) is still too thick. I was considering about a 0.5 - 1mm